# Java: Which is faster? Local variables or accessing encapsulation?

Tags: java, performance, variables, optimization, encapsulation

I recently read a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703539/local-variables-or-class-fields) that indicated, when accessing variables, it is faster to use the stack than the heap:

```
void f() {
    int x = 123; // <- located in stack
}

int x; // <- located in heap
void f() {
    x = 123  
}
```

However, I can't work it through my head which is faster in my example (since I assume they are both using the stack). I'm working on hitbox calculation and such, which uses alot of X-Y, width, height variables (up to 10-20 times for each) in the function.

Is it faster to use an object's `get()` method each time or set it to a local variable at the start of the function?

In code, is it faster to (or more efficient to):

```
void f() {
    doSomething(foo.getValue() + bar.getValue()); 
    doSomethingElse(foo.getValue(), bar.getValue());
    doAnotherThing(foo.getValue(), bar.getValue());
    // ... <- lot's of accessing (something.getValue());
}
```

or

```
void g() {
    int firstInt = foo.getValue();
    int secondInt = bar.getValue();

    doSomething(firstInt + secondInt);
    doSomethingElse(firstInt, secondInt);
    doAnotherThing(firstInt, secondInt);
    // ... <- lot's of accessing firstInt and secondInt
}
```

when `foo` and `bar` are `MyObject`'s

```
public class MyObject {
    int x = 1;
    public int getValue() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

If they are about the same efficiency, how many times do I have to perform a `.getValue()` for it to become less efficient?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't try and optimize your code like this. First make it work... in general, these micro-optimizations are meaningless. You need to benchmark changes in real code to determine if they matter for your use case.

Comment: Why does it make a difference? Please google search "premature optimization".

Comment: If you want to know where the turning point is for efficiency, you'll need to conduct a proper microbenchmark yourself. The answer varies with your hardware and your software.

Comment: I'm sure I'm not the only one that was unaware of the existence of benchmarking. My code does work, so I was simply asking if it does make a difference, and if anyone knew, what the difference was.

Comment: This isn't necessarily a micro-optimization.  `getValue` sounds like a local accessor, so the difference probably isn't too big, but it were `getValueFromDatabase` or `getExpensiveToComputeValue`, the difference would be noticeable pretty early on.  There's also readability;  if `a` and `b` are replaced with better names, `doSomething(foo,bar)` is much more descriptive than `doSomething(e.getValue,g.getValue)`.

Comment: I wouldn't trust the post you link. Measure properly and you will most certainly find no difference...

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Yes, it's a local accessor, thank you for the qualification. Also, I will make sure to improve the readability of my posts.

Comment: @snickers10m Oh, I didn't mean that _your_ post was unreadable.  I meant that using local variables can increase code readability.  Your post was fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[JIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) will change (optimize) your code on runtime, so this is not important in Java. One simple JIT optimization is [method inlining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073025/java-jit-method-inlining).

For further optimization read about [Micro Benchmarking](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/wiki/JavaMicrobenchmarks) and look at this question [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Answer (score -1):

If you do use local variables, you may tell the compiler that the value will not be changed `final int x = ...;`, turning it in some kind of local constant.

Reassigning values (recycling objects and such) may help reduce garbage collection (GC).

Write some extreme stress test, if possible a visual one too, let it run for a long time and measure real performance, perceived performance. A better faster time is not always better, sometimes it may be a bit slower but a bit smoother across the execution.